# Decimal places on hundreds of Excel graphs

Tags: excel, graph, format, vba

If I'm dealing with hundreds of graphs, which are right now automatically setting the y axis, how can I eliminate 10.0%, 20.0%, and make it simply 10%, 20% (a savings of 2 characters)?  I'm using Excel 2010, and don't want to mess up automatic formatting since there may be times that I need the percent decimal places, as in unemployment (4.5% is meaningful).  Of course, sometimes I graph stuff on the y axis in millions or billions of dollars (but that's a separate question).

Update: I found out that security rules **prohibit macros** in spreadsheets.  Can it be done without macros, by setting a value?  Perhaps that is something that the vendor (Microsoft) would do in future years....

Answer (score 1):

Right click the Y Axis you want to change.  Go to "Format Axis", and click "Number".  Here is where you can choose what type (accounting, number, percentage, etc) of formatting you want.  Just choose "Percentage" and put "0" for the "Decimal Places".

Macro which will do so for all charts in a worksheet:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim obj     As Object
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    With obj.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
       .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
    End With
Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, thank you, but the key phrase here is "I'm dealing with **hundreds** of graphs".  I don't want to / can't get to 100's of graphs, so is there a way to make Excel do that automatically, perhaps with a **macro** (one of the key words).

Comment: I found out an institutional roadblock that is (as I noted above in the Update):  for security reasons, macros are prohibited.  Maybe that dooms this question of mine, especially for such a minor / aesthetic fix.

Comment: Ooh - yeah, without the ability to use macros, I'm not sure if there's a quicker way.  I'm looking to see if you can change the default format for the Y axis, before you even create a chart.