# How to change decimal on x-axis (i.e. scatter graph), using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I was searching for how to change decimal, using VBA and I found the excellent answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32462504/9653254

However, for my graph, it is a scatter graph. So I need to change decimal on x-axis. Above code only change y-axis. Could you let me know how to change deciaml on x-axis?

Thank you in advance.

```
Dim obj     As Object
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
   With obj.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
      .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00"
   End With
Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: Also use `NumberFormat`  with `Axes(xlCategory)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved it!! many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer, thanks to @Ahmed AU

The code is the below. Thank you for your comment.

```
Sub xydecimal()

  Dim obj     As Object
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
   With obj.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
   .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00"
      End With
   With obj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00"            
   End With
Next obj

End Sub
```